How does triggers clicked worked in backbone.js
Recently, I have got a rails project project with backbone.js and CoffeeScript to support however I don't have previous work experience with backbone.js.
Some of model relationship of the projects are:
Project has many Parts
Project has many Notes
Part has many Notes
Have a page like below, from where I need to show a page with part notes on clicking to the number 3 and 1 with the red circle.

I have implement the page(http://localhost:3000/#parts/26859/notes) to show part notes through direct hit to the URL. Now I need to call/show the page from the view.js.coffee but I don't understand how the triggers work(or how I can call that). What does the colon(:) mean into the triggers - part:title:link:clicked
First triggers click is working fine to open part details page, looking to open part notes through second click - click .part-notes-link
view.js.coffee code given below. Would be great to have some suggestions and explanation using colon from experts.
.jst.eco
<p class="part-no">
<a class="part-title-link"><%= @title %></a>
<% if @notes > 0: %>
    <small class="badge notes">
        <a class="part-notes-link"><%= @notes %></a>
    </small>


view.js.coffee
@PartsTracking.module "Components.AnnotatedImage", (AnnotatedImage, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

class AnnotatedImage.Layout extends App.Views.Layout
    template:  "annotated_image/layout"
    className: "annotated-image"

    regions:
        image:                  ".image"
        partLinks:          ".part-links"
        editPartLink:       ".edit-part-link"

class AnnotatedImage.ImageView extends App.Views.ItemView
    template: "annotated_image/_image"
    className: "item"

    triggers:
        "click" : "image:clicked"

class AnnotatedImage.PartLinkView extends App.Views.ItemView
    template:   "annotated_image/_part_link"
    className:  "part-link"
    triggers:
        "click .part-title-link" : "part:title:link:clicked"
        "click .part-notes-link" : "part:notes:view:clicked"

class AnnotatedImage.PartLinksView extends App.Views.CompositeView
    template: "annotated_image/_part_links"
    className: "part-links-wrapper"
    itemView: AnnotatedImage.PartLinkView
    itemViewContainer: ".part-links"
    itemViewOptions: ->
        return (
            config:
                offset: true
        )

    triggers:
        "click" : "part:links:view:clicked"

Please let me know if I need to provide further information.
Thanks in advance.

Looks like triggers: is from Marionette rather than Backbone itself: https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/dom.interactions.html#view-triggers
